# Can I add a line at a certain price programmatically?

Tags: tradingview-api

I use [Cloud widgets Technical Analysis Charts](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?library=cloud-widget) . Can I add a red line at a certain price in the widget code? If yes, please tell me how it is done. Thank you. Shown in a screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMkkx.png)

Comment: What have you tried or looked up so far?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I did not find information on widget parameters that I can write in Javascript

Comment: @Sice60 did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @russelrillema Unfortunately no :(